# Color specific characters as they load into a RTB

Tags: vb6

I am writing a small CNC G-Code editor. I would like to load the code file into a rich text box (or other?) and color highlight the X,Y,Z,Rand F as it loads.

I've tried loading the file and parsing it afterwords by running through a character at a time to determine what it is and then coloring it but this is impossibly slow. some of my G-Code programs run to thousands of lines.

I know it can be done..... but in VB6??

Answer (score 0):

The richText controls can have RTF data "streamed" into it, or you can append text and set the colours as you go.

If it needs to be done "live" then do it when the cursor's line changes and recolour just the previous line.